# i can't install gnome-control-center ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: gnome

`

```
Depends: libcheese-gtk25 (>= 3.18.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese8 (>= 3.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.25.2) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libwacom2 (>= 1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-control-center-data (< 1:3.37) but 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5 is to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-online-accounts (>= 3.25.3) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: network-manager-gnome (>= 0.9.8) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-control-center-faces but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: rygel but it is not going to be installed or
                                    rygel-tracker but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`

I tried to fix but it didn't work

sudo apt install libcheese-gtk25
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libcheese-gtk25 : Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not installable
libcheese8 : Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not installable
libclutter-gst-3.0-0 : Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not installable
libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 : Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not installable
libcogl20 : Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Comment: I have the same issue for libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) for installing Microsoft Teams in ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Also this library caused issues since a century and Google finds a lot of results. What's wrong?